# HTML5 Detect Entering Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, fullscreen

I cannot seem to figure out how to bring an element into the fullscreen mode upon video entering the fullscreen mode. I tried looking through the various materials available but still the answer eludes me.
This is what I have so far:

```
 document.getElementById("videoid").addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
 document.getElementById("imageid").mozRequestFullScreen(); 
 }, false);
```

The code is for Firefox but I assume other browsers would have similar behavior only the prefix will have to be switched from "moz" to "webkit".

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/

Comment: @m93a I looked through the material and it didn't help; the problem is not bringing an object into fullscreen but doing it in response to video request to enter fullscreen.

Comment: There can't be two fullscreen elements at once. At first, you gotta do `document.closeFullScreen();`

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, there can't be two fullscreen elements at once. This code should work:

```
document.getElementById("videoid").addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
 if(document.mozfullScreen){
  document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  document.getElementById("imageid").mozRequestFullScreen();
 }
}, false);
```